# Should linters config files be in .gitignore?

Tags: git, static-analysis

Files like eslintrc, prettierrc or .editorconfig should be in .gitignore? Exist any good practice related to linters config?

Comment: no, because code style should be shared between developers (to force them to code in same style with the same config)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should check in (that is commit and not ignore) linter configuration files and editor-independent style and formatting configuration files (like `.editorconfig` or `.clang-format`).  It's important that these live in the repository because they set a style applicable to all developers and let all developers apply the same standards with their tools.  This is important for automated linting and formatting checking (e.g., via CI).

However, you should *not* check in any configuration file that is editor or developer specific.  For example, you would not check in a configuration file for Vim, because not all developers use Vim.  (You should not do this even if all of your developers *do* use the same editor, since settings may differ.)  Similarly, you would not check in a code signing file that indicated a particular developer's test certificate, because that would change per developer working on the project.  Those things should be listed in a user-specific `.gitignore` unless they are likely to be present on every developer's system (such as a project-specific config file), in which case the one in the repository is best.

Comment: Although they should be listed in a .gitignore, they should not be listed in the git ignore for the project.  Things like editor config files belong only in the user's global git ignore.  Otherwise, your project has to explicitly ignore config files for every editor in existence, which is clearly an impossible task.

Comment: I've updated the answer to mention that.  The exception is something every developer is likely to have, such as a config file every user will need, in which case you'd of course want that in the project-specific config.

Comment: Note that it may be reasonable to include, in the documentation, a sample editor configuration file (or section of that file) that will make one's editor more useful and/or pleasant. That is, you generally should not thrust your preferred settings upon users, but you may *offer* them your preferred settings :-)